# nginx asset (css/js) rewrite with subfolders - cache busting

Tags: javascript, css, nginx, url-rewriting

I have been using the nginx directives from the HTML Boilerplate github repository [here](https://github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate/)

The directives to allow cachebusting for CSS/JS assets is as follows:

```
location ~* (.+)\.(?:\d+)\.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif)$ {
  try_files $uri $1.$2;
}
```

This works really well for the following assets/locations:

```
/css/abc.123456.css -> /css/abc.css
/js/abc.123456.js   -> /css/abc.js
```

However if additional assets are under subfolders it does not match them.

```
/lib/jq/jquery.123456.css -> /lib/jq/jquery.css
/lib/jq/jquery.123456.js  -> /lib/jq/jquery.js
```

Any pointers are more than appreciated.

Comment: The evaluation order of regular expression `location` blocks is significant. Do you have other locations that may be conflicting, for example, for URIs beginning with `/lib/`?

Comment: Not at all. There is only one location `/` and this one.